# hibernate.connection.isolation being ignored?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to set isolation level READ_UNCOMMITED as the default isolation level for all my application.

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "myappEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "myappTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "com.example.dao" })
public class MyappDatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${myapp.datasource.db.driver}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;

    (...)

    @Bean(name = "myappDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.datasource")
    public DataSource myappDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "myappEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myappEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("myappDataSource") DataSource myappDataSource) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        props.put("hibernate.connection.isolation", Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = builder.dataSource(myappDataSource)
                .packages(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN).persistenceUnit("myapp").build();

        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(props);

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "myappTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager myappTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("myappEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory myappEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(myappEntityManagerFactory);
    }
```

But I still have to set isolation level individually

Example:

```
@Controller
public class MyappController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/items", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public List<Items> getItems() {

    }
```

Will not read uncommited unless I add isolation level again

```
@Controller
public class MyappController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/items", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional(value = "myappTransactionManager", isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public List<Items> getItems() {

    }
```

Am I missing something in my configuration?

```
    props.put("hibernate.connection.isolation", Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED);
```

Is not enough?

Comment: what is your database ? but i thinks it's not correct to set Isolation to READ_UNCOMMITTED in all over your application

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan Its a sql server 2008 database. I was ask to set noblock for all the application because there is very heavy use of some tables and some transactions may take several minutes.